# Kotlin 'let' usage

Tags: android, kotlin, let

Is there a difference between this piece of code:

```
fun isDogEating(): Boolean {
    return dog?.let { return it.eating } ?: false
}
```

and this

```
fun isDogEating(): Boolean {
    return dog?.eating ?: false
}
```

I bumped into something like the first and was wondering whether the `let` is redundant here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no differences in behavior.

Both functions return `false` if `dog == null`, because of the `?: false` at the end.

The `let` function is only executed if `dog != null`. 
Same with the `eating` property in the second example

Note that the `return` statement in the `let` lambda means to return from the `isDogEating` function, not from the lambda! To return from the lambda one may use the `return@let` or just the expression

I prefer a shorter version:

```
fun isDogEating() = dog?.eating ?: false
```

Comment: Great answer as always, Eugene!

Comment: I'd just add that in this case returning from `isDogEating` ends up not affecting the result, but mostly by accident.